# How to toggle between multiple user accounts

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am building an app where the user can have multiple accounts with different credentials (username, password) to access data on the server. Using CoreData, I save user credentials and have the user toggle between accounts. The problem I have is the account change doesn't take effect while using the app. You have to restart the app to see the effect. What I am trying to accomplish is similar to twitter app with more than one account. When you choose the account you see the tweets associated to that account. Below is the code I use for storing user credentials. What I have to do to have the similar user experience as twitter app account change?

```
// Credentials object where I use it to access user credentials
class Credentials{
    var name:String
    var url:String
    var username:String
    var password:String

    init(name:String, url:String, username:String, password:String){
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }
}

// Users managed object class for CoreData
class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var username: String
    @NSManaged var password: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var url: String
    @NSManaged var active: NSNumber
}

// The API class is where I pull the active user and set the Credentials object later I connect to my server with those credentials. 
// Request methods are omitted

class API {

    var credentials:Credentials!

    init(){
        self.credentials = getActiveStore()
        self.params = ["username":"\(credentials.username)", "password":"\(credentials.password)"]
    }

    func getActiveStore() -> Credentials?{
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "active = %@", 1 as NSNumber)

        var error:NSError?

        let fetchResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [User]
        if fetchResults.count == 1 {
            let name = fetchResults[0].name
            let url = fetchResults[0].url
            let consumerKey = fetchResults[0].username
            let consumerSecret = fetchResults[0].password
            return Credentials(name: name, url: url, username: username, password: password)
        }
        return Credentials(name: "", url: "", username: "", password: "")
    }
}
```

This function is in my UsersTableViewController. It gets called when the user taps the users to active that specific user.

```
private func updateStore(user:User){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    let fetchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", user.name)
    fetchRequest.predicate = fetchPredicate

    var error : NSError? = nil
    var fetchResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [User]
    if error != nil {
        println("An error occurred loading the data")
    } else {
        fetchResults[0].setValue(1, forKey: "active")

        var saveError : NSError? = nil
        if !managedContext.save(&saveError) {
            println("Could not update record")
        }else{
            credentials = Credentials(name: user.name, url: user.url, username: user.username, password: user.password)
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You say that "the account change doesn't take effect" but we don't know what that means. I can see that you're reloading some table view, does the table not display what you expected? If not then how does its data source work and why did you expect it to display data from some other user account? You seem to be setting a user's `active` attribute, what does that do? Do you ever unset the previous user's `active` attribute?

Comment: By that I meant I activate user when I select it in my UserTableViewController. I can see the user is activated when I select it, and I inactivate/unset other users. There is always one active user. I pull active user's credentials in my API object but the data I get from the server belongs to previous user that was active. You can see the effect I want to accomplish using Twitter app with two accounts. You can toggle between the accounts.