# How to reset and toggle API credentials

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app that can save multiple accounts to access my server API and retrieve data. Each account has its own credentials so the data pulled from server changes depending on which account is selected.

When my app runs first time, my API class checks my CoreData model to see which account is `active` and uses that account's credentials throughout the app. I can select a different account and set it as `active` and unset/inactivate all other accounts in my Accounts tableView and reset the `Credentials` object with the new selected account, but when I do my app still uses the account that the app first started with.

How do I structure my class to use the account's credentials that I select in my Accounts tableView? Below is my  API class I use. This class is called when my app starts.

```
class API {
 init(){
    self.credentials = getActiveStore()
    // I then use self.credentials to make API calls. 
    // Rest of the code is omitted for brevity
 }
func getActiveStore() -> Credentials?{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "active = %@", 1 as NSNumber) //NSPredicate(format: "active == YES", argumentArray: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    let fetchResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [WooStore]
    if fetchResults.count == 1 {
        let name = fetchResults[0].name
        let url = fetchResults[0].url
        let username = fetchResults[0].username
        let password = fetchResults[0].password
        return Credentials(name: name, url: url, username: username, password: password)
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Comment: what happens when `fetchResults` returns > 1?  Probably should put a logic trap in there just to be safe...

Comment: You are also not checking your `error` before assuming `fetchResults` exists.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the `NSManagedObject` that is returned as your credentials object.  There is no reason to create a new object that is just a copy of the `NSManagedObject`.

Subclass `NSManagedObject`, add any convenience methods that you want to the subclass and return it.

### Update

> My User is an NSManagedObject class which doesn't have an initializer

All objects have an initializer.  Even `NSManagedObject`.

However, you don't need to initialize the object because it is already initialized and populated!  It is sitting in your `fetchResults` array.

```
    if let cred = fetchResults.lastObject {
        return cred
    } else {
        return nil
    }
```

Instead of referencing the first object in the array over and over again just to construct some *other* object.

### Update

> and I still don't see the effect I want to have. The data still belongs to previous user after I selected different account.

Based on your code, you determine the active user based on a boolean flag in the persistent store.  While this is not a good idea, lets roll with it.

To change the user, you would need to set the current user's flag to 0.  Then you need to fetch the soon to be active user and set their flag to 1.  Then save the context so that the changes are persisted in the store.  Then this code will do what you expect it to do.

You would do all of that wherever in your app you are switching users.  NOT in the code you have provided here.

Comment: My `User` is an NSManagedObject class which doesn't have an initializer.

Comment: Okay, I now restructured my `User` class as follows

`convenience init(name:String, url:String, username:String, password:String, entity:NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self. username = username
        self.password = password
        
    }` and I still don't see the effect I want to have. The data still belongs to previous user after I selected different account.

Comment: Have you used twitter app with multiple users saved? That's what I want to accomplish pretty much.

Comment: I did not say to initialize the `NSManagedObject`.  I said it was already in memory, in existence.  Second, you did not state your issue was switching accounts!!!!  You need to be more specific in your questions.  Updated answer based on your feedback :/

Comment: You actually did say `Subclass NSManagedObject, add any convenience methods that you want to the subclass and return it.` I also stated in  my question my issue was switching accounts. Do you want to check this link you'll see my complete code there. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338077/how-to-toggle-between-multiple-user-accounts)

Comment: I see the account is activated, flag is set to YES. But my API class still uses the credentials when the app starts first.

Comment: By the way I appreciate the effort you put into this question.